# The approximation of an embedding of a manifold into a Euclidean space with certain conditions

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a compact smooth manifold with dimension $m$, $N$ is a smooth manifold with dimension $n$; $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{(m+n+1)}$ is a smooth embedding, $j:N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{(m+n+1)}$ is a smooth map.

**I want to prove that**: for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a smooth embedding $g:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{(m+n+1)}$, such that $\|g(p)-f(p)\|<\epsilon$ for all $p\in M$, and $g(M)$ and $j(N)$ have no intersection.

**What I have tried**: I managed to use partition of unity to reduce the question to charts, also I think it probably needs Whitney Approximation Theorem, but I do not know how to use it. Can someone help me?

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the (parametric) transversality theorem, I believe.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I just learned about it because of your advice, and I think this theorem might help, but the theorem applies to $j$, not $f$, is there any trick I can use to tackle it?

Comment: Here's the trick: Apply the theorem to (a particular family of perturbations of) $f\times j\colon M\times N\to\Bbb R^{m+n+1}\times\Bbb R^{m+n+1}$, with the closed submanifold $\Delta$ (the diagonal) of the range. I highly recommend you look at Guillemin and Pollack (and, if you're more sophisticated, Hirsch's *Differential Topology*).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your generous advice, I've figured out a solution (without using the diagonal), could you please help me check if it's correct? P.S. The books you recommended are excellent for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}$ be an open ball centered at $0$, then consider the continuous map:
$$\begin{align*}
J: S\times N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}
\\ (s,q) \mapsto j(q)+s
\end{align*}$$
For any fixed $q \in N$, $J$ is a translation of $S$, thus a submersion at $q$. So $J$ is just a submersion of $S\times N$ and therefore transversal to $f(M)$. According to the Transversality Theorem, for almost every $s \in S$, the map $J_s(q) = j(q)+s$ is transversal to $f(M)$.

Choose such $s$ that is non-zero and small enough. Since $dim (f(M)) +dim(N) = m+n <dim(\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1})$, "$J_s$ is transversal to $f(M)$" is equivalent to
say that $f(M) \cap J_s(N) = \emptyset$. Let $g(p) = f(p)-s$ be a smooth embedding from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}$, it is not difficult to see that $g(M) \cap j(N) = \emptyset$ and such $g$ satisfied all the conditions we want.

Comment: Ah, clever to switch the roles of $f$ and $j$. I missed that.